# HTTPS with Java Server Faces

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat

I'm trying to deploy my Java Server Faces app on tomcat. I want the app only to be accessible using HTTPS. I'm finding that when I move from page to page the application falls back to http. If I modify the url in the browser to use https then the page is displayed.

I'm clearly missing some configuration somewhere. Can anyone suggest where?

Answer (score 1):

2 things you can do:

Disable HTTP connector in `server.xml`.

Add this `<security-constraint>` to your web.xml:

```xml
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Entire Web App</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <user-data-constraint>
    <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
  </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

This will automatically redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS.